# "CAN NOT RESLOVE THE VARIABLE CAMERA" error on Asking permission at run time

Tags: android, android-permissions

> ```
>    MainActivity camera button onClickListener
> ```

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    //                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    //                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    askPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
                    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                }
            });
```

> Snipett from Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ds.texar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I can't get rid off that "CAMERA" on which the compiler is showing "variable can't resolve" error. What should I do. I've already added camera permission in my android manifest. I am not getting what's wrong with that.
Actually I am getting same error with every permission.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Manifest file I was including during the permission in onClick method was the project Manifest but replacing that with android Manifest will do the work fine.